# Unorder_map vs. struct for larger field size

Tags: c++

Wonder if the unorder_map<key, value> is more efficient than simple struct when applying to, for example model a cache line:

```
struct c_key {
    uint_4  pte,
    bit     valid,   // just 1-bit wide
    bit     dirty,   // just 1-bit
    uint_21 tag
};

std::unorder_map<c_key, data> cache_line;  // data is 32-byte
...

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 4-bit page_table_entry | 1-bit valid | 1-bit dirty | 21-bit tag | 32B data    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

if use unorder_map's key field for the first 4 fields (defined in a struct), the key.first() points to all 27-bit where further indexing is needed to point to particular field. For example, need to use key.first().valid to extract the valid field. Is a direct struct declaration more efficient?

```
struct cache_line {
    uint_4  pte,
    bit     valid,   // just 1-bit
    bit     dirty,   // just 1-bit
    uint_21 tag,
    int_32B data
};
```

Comment: I get what the question is asking, but your examples suggest a problem with understanding what the memory layout of such a structure would be. `bool`s do not occupy 1 bit, they occupy at least a byte. And even if `uint_4`/`uint_21` were bitfields, AFAIK they would not continue from the _same_ bitfield in this definition because bitfields require the same underlying type to be used, and for it to all be common to the same structure

Comment: No matter what, you're going to need 8 bytes, 4 for the bitfields and 4 for the data.  Really depends on how you want to work with the data.  A `vector<cache_line>` would work for many applications.

Comment: @Human-Compiler haha... you're absolutely right, bool is not one-bit wide. I just used it to highlight the bit width. Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Comment: @visitor99999 If this is meant to just be more of a "pseudo-code"-ish example, then it might be worthwhile to mention that  in the question -- just to help clarify

Comment: @Human-Compiler yup, just updated it

Comment: @NathanOliver if use vector<cache_line>, that means the size is dynamic. But there is no need to have dynamic size. In other words, only lines inside would be operated, e.g., compare the tag field, remove, add, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but the difference will likely have more to do with the characteristics of the containers than anything else.

`std::unordered_map` stores its entries in a `std::pair`, which will store its two elements contiguously in memory.  That is, as far as access to elements goes, `std::pair<int,int>` and `struct Foo { int first, second; }` will likely be exactly the same.

---

What *will* make a performance difference is the container you use.  For example the performance characteristics of a `std::unordered_map` will be different from those of a `std::vector` due to things like hashing overhead and memory locality of its elements.  Pick the container that fits your usage patterns.